# Failing to use numeric characters within Ruby array as indices for a string

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to use the numeric charecters from the array held within the `positions`  argument as indices to access the characters of the string inside the `string` argument to subsequently print a new string. I have an idea of what I need to do to get it to work, but I am hung up.

*Total code thus far:*

```
  def scramble_string(string, positions)
    str = string
    pos = positions.join
    newstr = []
    i = 0
    while i < pos.length do
      return newstr.push(str[pos[i]])
      i += 1
    end
  end
  scramble_string("hello", [2, 3, 4, 5])
```

*I suspect my problem lies within this part of the code...*

```
return newstr.push(str[pos[i]])
```

Comment: Why the need for positions at all? Are you just trying to jumble the string because you can do that with `"hello".chars.shuffle.join`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you, you can use the following to get a given substring of a string, using a [range](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html):

```
'this is a string'[5..8]
 => "is a"
```

A simple way would be:

```
str = 'this is a string'
positions = [2,3,6,9,10]
new_str = positions.map {|p| str[p]}.join
=> "iss s"
```

Comment: Could you articulate the meaning of this part of your code please? Thanks.
`new_str ||= ''
  new_str << str[position]`

Comment: `new_str ||= ''` means basically `new_str = '' if new_str.nil?` and `new_str << str[position]` is like saying push the character in `str` at the `position` onto the end of `new_str`

Comment: you can also push things onto the front of a string using `>>`.. some people call this 'shovelling'

Comment: @ErikÁsland I updated my answer in a way that I might actually use if I were trying to do what I think you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was very helpful. 

Why doesn't `newstr.push(str[pos[i]])` work?

Answer (score 0):

```
str = 'this is a string'
positions = [2,3,6,9,1]

str.split('').values_at(*positions).join
  #=> "iss h"
```

Another way, one that does not use `join`:

```
positions.each_with_object('') { |i,s| s << str[i] }
```